# URI Equivalent of encode_www_form_component in Addressable

Tags: ruby, uri, addressables

What is the equivalent method for `URI.encode_www_form_component` in `Addressable::URI`?

Comment: [Docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/Addressable/URI#form_encode-class_method) seems like you are looking for `form_encode` or maybe `encode_component`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the [`#encode_component`](https://rubydoc.info/gems/addressable/Addressable/URI#form_encode-class_method) method. Beware that `Addressable` will use full percentage mode, and replace a space with `%20` instead of `+`:

```
Addressable::URI.encode_component('a decoded string with email@example.com', Addressable::URI::CharacterClasses::UNRESERVED)
# => "a%20decoded%20string%20with%20email%40example.com"

URI.encode_www_form_component('a decoded string with email@example.com')
# => "a+decoded+string+with+email%40example.com"
```

If you compare the two methods that encode a full set of key/value parameters, you will see instead that they behave more similarly:

```
[15] pry(main)> Addressable::URI.form_encode([["q", "a decoded string with email@example.com"]])
=> "q=a+decoded+string+with+email%40example.com"
[16] pry(main)> URI.encode_www_form([["q", "a decoded string with email@example.com"]])
=> "q=a+decoded+string+with+email%40example.com"
```

I was actually surprised when I tested it. So [I dug into the source code of `Addressable`](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable/blob/60feb48d345ad0d4cec5991fe20c5f38f5252ce9/lib/addressable/uri.rb#L753-L768), and I found the `form_encode` method makes an explicit replacement of `%20` with `+`:

```
escaped_form_values = form_values.map do |(key, value)|
  # Line breaks are CRLF pairs
  [
    self.encode_component(
      key.gsub(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/, "\r\n"),
      CharacterClasses::UNRESERVED
    ).gsub("%20", "+"),
    self.encode_component(
      value.gsub(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/, "\r\n"),
      CharacterClasses::UNRESERVED
    ).gsub("%20", "+")
  ]
end
```

So here's your options:

1. Use `#encode_component` as it is
2. Use `#encode_component` and explicitly replace `%20` with `+` if you need to reproduce the same output
3. Use `#form_encode` if you have a key/value form fields